# Powershell function issue

Tags: function, powershell

Error I'm getting is the following

Missing closing '}' in statement block.

I'm using this to automate adding user to a .dat file which has hundreds of user's for one of our systems. I was task with taking this part over and well I don't like to do anything manually. So I wrote a script to do 95% of it for me and it removes user's just fine. But this function I'm trying here adds the user in 2 different specific places to keep it nice and net. I'm still learning powershell so any direction would be great and you wont hurt my feelings I'm no pro nor novice here.

```
Function Add{
$username = Read-Host "User to add to REP01-02 Printing"
$LOCreportADD1 = "\\rep01\E$\orant\Report60\Server\cgicmd.dat"
$LOCreportADD2 = "\\rep02\e$\orant\Report60\Server\cgicmd.dat"
$Username1 = $username+": "
$prd = "prd: "
$userid = "userid="
$henation = "/henation@rmsprd %*"


$Text1 = get-content $LOCreportADD1
$Text2 = get-content $LOCreportADD2

$NewText1 = @()
foreach ($Line in $Text1) {
    if ($Line -eq "Insert new user1") {
        $Line = $Line.Replace("Insert new user1 \", "Insert new user1 \")
        $NewText1 += $Line
        $NewText1 += $username1+$userid+$username+$henation
    }
    Elseif ($Line -eq "New User2") {
        $Line = $Line.Replace("New User2 \", "New User2 \")
        $NewText12 += $Line
        $NewText12 += $username+$prd+$userid+$username+$henation
}
$NewText1 | Set-Content $LOCreportADD1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says it all. You are missing a `}` at the end to close the function.

Tips is to put your script in an editor (Like Notepad++) that can handle `{}` matching and it's easy to see if you miss a `{`/`}`.

Answer (score 2):

The error says it all. You are missing a '}' at the end to close the foreach block..

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Add{
    $username = Read-Host "User to add to REP01-02 Printing"
    $LOCreportADD1 = "\\rep01\E$\orant\Report60\Server\cgicmd.dat"
    $LOCreportADD2 = "\\rep02\e$\orant\Report60\Server\cgicmd.dat"
    $Username1 = $username+": "
    $prd = "prd: "
    $userid = "userid="
    $henation = "/henation@rmsprd %*"


    $Text1 = get-content $LOCreportADD1
    $Text2 = get-content $LOCreportADD2

    $NewText1 = @()
    foreach ($Line in $Text1) {
        if ($Line -eq "Insert new user1") {
            $Line = $Line.Replace("Insert new user1 \", "Insert new user1 \")
            $NewText1 += $Line
            $NewText1 += $username1+$userid+$username+$henation
        }
        Elseif ($Line -eq "New User2") {
            $Line = $Line.Replace("New User2 \", "New User2 \")
            $NewText12 += $Line
            $NewText12 += $username+$prd+$userid+$username+$henation

        } # <---- This is your missing brace, to close out the Else condition

    }
    $NewText1 | Set-Content $LOCreportADD1
}
```

Comment: Thx to everyone it allows the function to work fine now just doesn't work the way i was hoping it would.

Answer (score 0):

In the Powershell ISE you can highlight a '}'. It will then highlight the bracket it forms a block of code with. Highlight it, then right click it. Makes it easier to find your problem.